# Any reason these HTML entites just display in plain text?

Tags: html, wordpress, html-entities

I have a BBPress installation on my Wordpress site, and one of the posts includes this lump of text: `R&&#2384; pH&#127917` and they render like this: "R&ॐpH🎭"

I want it to render like that on my page, but for some reason it just displays in plain text like the first instance above.

I have tried setting the follow HTML meta values in the `<head>` of my page:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

And the HTTP headers look like this:

```
http://redacted.com/forums/topic/slug

GET /forums/topic/they-died-with-their-boots-on/ HTTP/1.1
Host: redacted.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 14 Nov 2014 10:41:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.4-14+deb7u14
X-Pingback: http://redacted.com/xmlrpc.php
Link: <http://redacted.com/?p=202>; rel=shortlink
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 5204
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=98
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Not sure what to try next.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Is that text input in the visual editor, or the text editor of the WYSIWYG?

Comment: You need to show the actual HTML content as received by a browser (use View Source and then copy and paste). If they have `&amp;` instead of `&`, as they probably have, you next have to find out why—probably because WordPress encodes `&` characters that when entered in WYSIWYG mode.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with encoding. The `&#1234;` part is an entitized unicode character (with `1234` being the code-point).

To prevent it being entitized, just replace the ampersand with the ampersand entity: `&amp;` so your rendered HTML should look like this...

`R&amp;&amp;#2384; pH&amp;#127917`

...which will then render like this:

> R&&#2384; pH&#127917

Comment: You edited my post, and in so doing reversed the meaning of it.  The problem isn't that they're rendering, the problem is that they're *not* rendering.  I want them to draw the proper characters, but instead they look like  
`R&&#2384; pH&#127917`

Comment: @Zacharia my apologies. In that case the problem is that the ampersands **are** being entitised so you just need to ensure that they're being rendered directly. This sounds like a simple usage issue with BBPress/Wordpress. Alternatively, I suggest removing the entities completely and storing the characters literally, assuming your system is fully Unicode-compliant.

Comment: How does one "just ensure that they're being rendered directly"?  The database has hundreds of thousands of posts in it - updating every character would take a long time.

Comment: If the HTML is (incorrectly) entitised in your database then you could use PHP's `html_entity_decode` function when rendering the content - but be careful in case the content contains angle-brackets that aren't meant to be decoded.